# I've lost everything on my desktop?

Tags: 11.10, upgrade

I'm an uneducated ubuntu user, I updated to 11.10 and while i was changing some settings in compiz and I lost all of my desktop icons...well everything except for-file, edit, view, bookmarks, go and help! I have no idea how to resolve the problem, please help me!! Is there a way to fix the problem in the terminal or open the control centre from terminal?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any case, you can login using the Ubuntu 2D option. You choose it with the button next to the password field when you login. It's quite nice too, so you can use it until you can fix your problem permanently. :)

Comment: Thanks Jo, that worked perfectly! Think I need to do some Ubuntu related studying!!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem,fresh from update in the user i carried over from the last version(11.04). In a new user the 3d unity work fine. I think it was due to conflicting software from the last version that is no longer compatible with 11.10. i fixed it by logging into the 2d unity> top right menu>startup applications then deselected all. log out then log back into the 3d unity.

If it is the same problem as mine hopefully this fixes the problem. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem due to compiz crashing. My crash was due to the `nautilus-open-terminal` package triggering a bug elsewhere. So first make sure you don't have that package installed.

Then you can reset unity by typing the following into a terminal:

```
unity --reset
```

If that doesn't work, please post the output of the above command.

Comment: I used that command line and it came back saying -compiz (core) - Warn: failed to receive ConfigureNotify event from request at 143983 (now: 446857)

compiz (core) - Warn: unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0x1600093!
compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen. you shouldprobably file a bug about this.
What do you recommend?

Comment: @Mike: I recommend you file a bug. The command for that would be `apport-bug compiz` which should do everything for you. [This is the nearest bug I can find](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/869293) - do you use nvidia graphics or a second monitor? Good luck. Also if compiz is the problem then you could use Unity 2D (as suggested by Jo-Erlend) as that doesn't use compiz. You can select Unity 2D on the login screen by clicking on one of the buttons next to the password box.

Comment: Thanks Hamish, I'll report the bug and let you know the result, thanks again. m

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely just Nautilus that crashed/doesn't start up, your files will still be in `/home/your_name/Desktop` an reachable with the file browser of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that suddenly your desktop was empty and you miss the files - not explicitly the icons...

Just a guess:When you play with the language settings, Ubuntu might ask you to rename you Desktop folder. I have seen things going wrong here and I ended with an empty desktop.
Look into your home directoy and check whether there are two Desktop folders in two different languages.

E.g. "Arbeitsfläche" (de) and "Desktop" (en). Check both folders for your files...