# Problem with Lubuntu in a moment all desktop icons lost and i cant create new icons on my desktop, why?

Tags: lubuntu, icons

Hello all i need your help !

Am using Lubuntu last version (in Greek language), is updated and i had till now no problem.

Just now, in a moment with no reason, all the icons of my Desktop disappeared and i cant copy any new icons from other folders to my Desktop anymore and even i cant create any new icons on Desktop !

I dont understand whats going on here and whats the problem... !? I really dont know..

Please HELP me to fix this very strange problem that occurred !

See this picture, am getting this message, when am trying to copy any icon on desktop :

[image]

http://i39.tinypic.com/2ikb7s6.png

Edit - Image translation: "The process is complete but there are errors"

Answer (score 0):

[I've lost everything on my desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67514/ive-lost-everything-on-my-desktop) has a specific suggestion; check to make sure there aren't two Desktop folders, one in Greek and one in another language.

Also, as per that link, try restarting the pcmanfm file manager in Lubuntu from a terminal emulator { Ctrl-Alt-T }.

Comment: There are not 2 desktop folders, whats the command syntax for restarting pcmanfm ? Am newbie in linux.. plz help to resolve this strange issue

Comment: Open a terminal window from the menu then type in the word pcmanfm and press {Enter}